# File Transfer between Computers Using Remoting/WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, file-transfer, .net-remoting

I need to UpLoad File/Folder from one Computer to another without using basic File Sharing how can this be done using WCF...

I have found Examples... like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33825/WCF-TCP-based-File-Server) but in this the File Transfer is between a Server and a Client....

In my Case any computer can be a server and others can be Client i.e the application can be invoked from any computer to transfer files between others... Can this be done... using Remoting/WCF...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [WCF Peer-to-Peer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx) is what you're looking for.